# Which countries invest their state pension in their stock market and its effects?

Tags: financial-economics

I apologise in advance if this is not the right stack exchange site to ask this question.

China has started investing its state pension fund in the stock market on full scale recently.

I know Norway has a pension fund which is built from its profits from oil profit. Canada also has a fund.

I am wondering how common this is? What are the effect on the stock market or economy as a whole when the government take such action?

Comment: Japan does it too. It will be very hard to provide an exhaustive list of countries that do so.

Comment: Actually i found a non-exhaustive list: http://www.oecd.org/finance/financial-markets/40196093.pdf so now i am more interested in its economic implications